# How to make Vim to auto format the name of the function to be capitalize in Go

Tags: go, vim, vim-go

I use Vim as an editor for coding in Go. I has vim-go installed in my Vim.
I wonder if there is a way to auto format the function name to make it capitalize.
For example instead of type

```golang
fmt.Println("Go is fun")
```

I would like to just type

```golang
fmt.println("Go is fun")
```

and produce the result of `fmt.Println`

It would help me type the code smoothly and avoid to let my right little finger to touch to shift button for the method name.

Comment: There may be a vim add-on that can do this, but: consider how that might affect your own habits in terms of *defining* exported vs unexported names...

Comment: See `:help abbreviations`.